# Django Python загрузка файлов(картинки) на странице

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

Нужно сделать чтобы загружаемая картинка появлялась на странице
Подскажите как отловить картинку и сразу её вставить на странице?

html форма

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
     <p><input type="file" name="f">
     <input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form>
  {{ form }}
```

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        # file is saved
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()
return render(request, 'poll/articles.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задача в том, чтобы показать превью загружаемой картинки, то это делается прямо на странице с помощью javascript, можно сделать как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Если нужно показать пользователю картинку, которую он загрузил на сервер через форму, то эту картинку нужно сначала сохранить на сервере и дать к ней доступ по ссылке, а потом вернуть эту ссылку(в теге `<img src="{}">` она автоматически загрузится и отобразится пользователю).

Comment: Дело в том что у меня вообще не получается картинку на сервер загрузить

Answer (score 0):

Вы что то забыли.

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # А кто форму будет сохранять? А проверять?
        if form.is_valid(): # <-----------------------------------
            form.save() # <---------------------------------------
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, ('poll/articles.html', {'form': form}))
```

---

Куда будет сохраняться задается в MEDIA_ROOT в settings.py и в модели upload_to параметре поля.

Получить URL на картинку можно через object.image_field.url

Используйте модели, или опишите, чего вы ходите добиться, смысл этой формы с картинкой

PS: Почитайте документацию

Comment: Исправил,но я всё равно не пойму как мне получить картинку(где она) и где(как) задать путь куда она будет сохраняться

Comment: Обвновил для вас